find the explicit Solution $u$ and check that if $u\in H^2(I)
we considere $I=]a,b[$ and
$$V=\{ u\in H^1(I) : u(\frac{1}{2})=0\}$$
$1)$ Prove that $V$ is an Hilbert space and $v\to \|u'\|$ is equivalente to norm of $H^1(I)$ 
$2)$ Show there exists a unique $v\in V$ such that $\int u'v' dx =v(0)$
$3)$ Interpret the problem and find the  explicit Solution $u$ and check that if $u\in H^2(I)$\
I managed to prove that $(1)$ and the $2$ by showing that $V$ is closed subspace and by Lax-miligram we prove the existance and unicity. any help for question $3$. Thank you

what is $a,b$? a hint for 3: the solution $u$ will be piecewise linear with kink at $t=0$.
